# inner join with aggregation pipelines

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a set of documents with an array of sub-documents in MongoDB, cut down schemas below:

Items:

```
const itemSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['active','inactive','quarantine','deleted']
    },
    subitems: [{
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'subitem'
    }]

});
```

Sub Items:

```
const subItemSchema = new Schema({
    parent: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'item',
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['active','inactive','deleted']
    },
    number: Number
});
```

I am trying to query the items to find sub-items with a certain number, in MongoDB I can do the following:

```
[{$lookup: {
  from: 'subitems',
  localField: 'subitems',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'subitems'
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$subitems",
  includeArrayIndex: 'string',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
}}, {$match: {
  "subitems.number": 29
}}]
```

This correctly returns me a single document with the single subitem I am looking for.

Now when I try this in mongoose:

```
let foundItems = await Item.aggregate([
    {
      '$lookup': {
        'from': 'subitems', 
        'localField': 'subitems', 
        'foreignField': '_id', 
        'as': 'subitems'
      }
    }, {
      '$unwind': {
        'path': '$subitems', 
        'includeArrayIndex': 'string', 
        'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': false
      }
    }, {
      '$match': {
        'subitems.number': term,
        'status': {'$ne': 'deleted'}
      }
    }
  ]);
```

I always get no documents.

I have also tried to do this with a basic populate:

```
Items.find({
    status: {"$ne": 'deleted'}
  })
  .populate({
    path: 'subitems',
    match: {
      number: term
    }
  });
```

However this returns the correct item but with all it's subitems.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I was passing the number to the match function as a string, Mongo didn't consider `31` and `"31"` equal.